# Unexpected stack memory cleanup

Tags: java, recursion, memory

Why function with the name `first` throw StackOverflowError but function with the name `second` not?

```
public static void first ( String [] args){
    recursion(50, 5);
    recursion(500, 50);
    recursion(5000, 500);
}

public static void second ( String [] args){
    recursion(5000, 500);
    recursion(5000, 500);
    recursion(5000, 500);
}

public static void recursion(int upper , int lower){
    if (upper < lower){
        System.out.println("Recursion finished.");
    } else {
        recursion(upper - 1, lower);
        System.out.println(upper + "");
    }
}
```

Environment: *openjdk 14.0.2, 2,3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9, 16 GB 2400 MHz DDR4*

Comment: updated in order to avoid misunderstanding

Comment: works also fine for me - Java 12 , AMD Ryzen 5, 8GB, Netbeans 12

Comment: Reproduced with JVM param -Xss1024k

Comment: The problem is related to JIT. If you disable JIT by specifying `-Djava.compiler=NONE`, both `first` and `second` completes without error. If you keep JIT enabled, but comment out the second `println` statement, both completes without error. If you force instant JIT with option `-Xcomp`, both completes without error. It just seems that the question code accidentally hit that sweet spot (or should I say *sour* spot) where some code have been JIT optimized and some have not, and that mixture causes extra stack space usage, causing the error.

Comment: @Andreas if you want, you can summarize it as an answer

Comment: I don't want, since I don't think this is of use to anyone else. You hit a quirk of a particular JIT and a peculiar set of circumstances. Adjust anything in that code, and the 2 methods behave the same. This is a fringe condition, and of no use, since the code is flawed (too deep recursion). Fix the recursion, and you'll never see the problem.